# how to run main thread at the end after all other threads completed

Tags: java, multithreading

I wanted to know how does `thread's` `join()` method works. I was assuming that when we give `t.join()` after `t.start()`, then the rest of the threads may be `main` will execute after Thread t has completed its process. When I  execute the following code :

```
public class Run extends Thread {
    void go(){
        System.out.println(isAlive());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Thread t=new Run();
        t.start();
        //t.join();
        ((Run)t).go();
    }   
}
```

I could get either `true` or `false` in output. If `t.start()` executes before `((Run)t).go()` , then output will be `true` or else `false` But I want to get output as always `true`. So I uncomment the line `t.join()`, so that `main` thread's `((Run)t).go()` gets executes at the end. But now I always get the output as `false`. I expected it to be true. can any one clear away my confusions? I know I have not included Thread's `run()` method.

Comment: You must override the "run" method. Copy paste error?

Comment: no i did that intentionally to see the behavior. It does compiles fine even without run method

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--

> Waits for this thread to die.

Your program has two threads:  the Main thread and the instance of Run.  When the main thread calls `t.join()`, it will wait until `t` dies, then proceed.  So after `Thread.join()` returns, the thread will, by definition, be dead.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know how does thread's join() method works.

How it works? or what it does?

What it does is, `t.join()` waits until thread `t` is dead.  (I.e., you call it, and it doesn't return until `t` is dead).

How it works is, it sits in a loop, testing the status of the thread and calling `t.wait()` if the thread is not dead yet.  One of the last things the thread does as it dies is to change its state and then call `t.notifyAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to get output as always `true`. So I uncomment the line `t.join()`, so that main thread's `((Run)t).go()` gets executes at the end.

If you want the result to be `true`, you need to ensure that that the thread is alive when you check; the most straightforward way is to check from the running thread (i.e., from the thread's target `run()` method), but if you need to check from another thread, you'd need to create a synchronization mechanism between the threads, like a `CountdownLatch`. Then, the thread would wait to die until the main thread has checked its status.

However, all this seems very contrived. The `join()` method waits for another thread to die. If you check that thread after `join()` has successfully completed, of course you will see that it is not alive.

Answer (score 0):

join()- waits for the thread to die.`enter code here`

```
class JoinDemo{
   Thread thread1 = new Thread(
                 new Runnable() {
                     public void run () {
                         //your code logic goes here
                     }
                  }
    );
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(
                 new Runnable() {
                     public void run () {
                         //your code logic goes here
                     }
                  }
    );
    thread1.start(); //line1
    thread1.join();  //line2
    thread2.start();//line3
}
```

Here in this example there are 3 threads, main,thread1,thread2. Currently running thread ie. main will wait for the thread1 to die.After thread1 dies, it will contniue to execute thread2. **So main thread will come to line3 only after thread1 dies.**